# CSS HTML: Horizontal Tabs

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have some HTML and CSS that is mostly doing what I am trying to achieve.  The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/8YX7M/.

What I would really like is to have a page border attached to the tabs so that selected tab is simply an extension of the page while the unselected tabs all have a black line underneath them showing that they are not an extension of the current page.  Also, I am wondering how one goes about displaying content under a set of tabs.  Do you use something like a frame to load the new content selected by the tab or do you make a new page of each possible tab and load the whole thing.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: The content is going to be various dashboards, charts and Excel reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ and re-skin it hooking the classes you get for free.

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I have been looking for.  I've been all over the web with this.  I can't believe I didn't find this.

Answer (score 3):

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/8YX7M/1/)

added:

```
.tablist li a{
    boder-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

.tablist li a.active{
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    background:#fff;    
}
```

And the class `active` to the `a` HTML element:

```
<li><a href="#Dashboard" class="active" ><strong>Tutorialsphere</strong></a></li>
```